# How to let an Animal object know what Room it is in through a reference

Tags: java, oop, reference

I am working with two separate classes, `Animal` and `Room`. A `Room` is instantiated with an array within. `Animal` objects are then instantiated and placed in the array within the `Room`. How can I give the `Animal` objects a reference to what `Room` they are placed into so when I call a `look()` method on them, they can return the name of the Room they are in?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Room mainRoom = new Room("The Lobby");

Animal gizmo = new Animal("Gizmo");        
mainRoom.addAnimal(gizmo);

System.out.println(mainRoom.toString());

gizmo.look();
}
```

-

```
public class Room {

private String name;
private Animal[] animals;
private Room currentRoom;
int i = 0;


public Room(String name) {
setName(name);
animals = new Animal[10];
}

public String toString() {
String temp = new String();
temp += "\nThis room is " + name + ".\n\n";
temp += "In the lobby are the following animals: \n";
for (Animal s : animals) {
    temp += s.toString() + "\n";
}
return temp;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public void addAnimal(Animal a) {
    if (i < 10) {
    if (animals[i] != null) {
    i++;
    addAnimal(a);
    } else {
    animals[i] = a;

    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Room full");
}
}

}
```

-

```
public class Animal {

private Room currentRoom;
private String name;

public Animal() {
}

public Animal(String name) {
setName(name);
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String toString() {
return "\t" + name;
}

public void look() {
    System.out.println(name + " is currently in " + getCurrentRoom());
//getCurrentRoom().toString();
}

public Room getCurrentRoom() {
return this.currentRoom;
}

public void setCurrentRoom(Room currentRoom) {
this.currentRoom = currentRoom;
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for your Room class using recursion in the addAnimal method? The whole method seems to be a bit weird design wise

Comment: No reason really, other than it was an alternative to using a try/catch. My error message just needs to display "Room full" and since I'm not using an ArrayList I figure I would use this approach. I also tend to overthink simple things.

Comment: It's just that you actually never reset i to 0, so a simple if i < yourNumber check should be enough. If it is, just add the animal to array[i] and increment i by one afterwards Right now you have an unnecessary function call ever time you insert something. Also for your toString method, consider using StringBuilder for improved performance.

Comment: Huh, now that I look back on it the next day, I have no idea why I did that! Thanks for pointing that out, I cleaned it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most elegant solution will be inside the addAnimal function of the Room like this

```
  public void addAnimal(Animal a) {
    if (i < 10) {
        if (animals[i] != null) {
            i++;
            addAnimal(a);
        } else {
            animals[i] = a;
            a.setCurrentRoom(this); // Setting room of animal
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Room full");
    }
}
```

Comment: So far, this answer seems to work perfectly. It will only assign the Room if the Animal object was able to be placed in the Room in the first place. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I give the Animal objects a reference to what Room they are
>   placed into so when I call a look() method on them, they can return
>   the name of the Room they are in?

You should set the room within Animal instead:

```
Animal gizmo = new Animal("Gizmo");    
gizmo.setCurrentRoom(mainRoom);    // this would set mainRoom as the attribute of gizmo
```

Further your code here:

```
public void look() {
    System.out.println(name + " is currently in " + getCurrentRoom());
    //getCurrentRoom().toString();
}
```

would fetch the `currentRoom` as set by the code above.

Answer (score 1):

`gizmo.setCurrentRoom(mainRoom);` 

(If construct `Animal` object within `Room` use : `gizmo.setCurrentRoom(this)`)

You could also add `String getRoomName() {return currentRoom.getName();}` to `Animal` class.